# Creating UI problem

Tags: .net, visual-c++, user-interface

I am creating a program which has an installer-like interface. Is it better to implement it with `ShowDialog` method of `Form` class or doing an MDI interface? Below are the ways I tried  to do it using the `ShowDialog` method, and the problems I have with them:

1) First form `ShowInTaskbar` property is set to `true`, other form is set to `false`. Form is shown by `.ShowDialog()` method in response to button `"Next>"` click event, click event of `"<Back"` button invokes `.Close()` method. In this case forms appear in modal mode, it's bad experience for me.

2) All forms have `ShowInTaskbar` property set to true; form is shown by `.ShowDialog()` method in response to click event of button `"Next>"` (same event handler sets `.Visible=false` to hide the form); on click event of `"<Back"` button invoke `.Close()` method. In this case when pressing `Next` or `Back` closing and opening a new window is visible in the in the task bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually wizard-type interfaces are implemented by having one window (`Form`) and replacing its content on `Next` / `Back` buttons press.

It's a bit confusing what UI framework you are using, as you tagged your question with Visual C++ which would suggest MFC, ATL/WTL or Win32, but you also tagged it with .Net and the methods and properties you are mentioning suggest WinForms.

If you are using WinForms, the easiest way would be to create several [`Panel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel(v=VS.90).aspx) instances on your your form that contain the groups of controls you currently have on the different forms and just show/hide the right `Panel` depending on which button was pressed and what is the previous visible `Panel`.

An alternative would be to use the [`TabControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.aspx) with hidden tab buttons and just change the selected tab on button press.

A blog post that provides some sample implementation of a [generic wizard control](http://weblogs.asp.net/justin_rogers/articles/111146.aspx).

And an old thread on social.msdn.com that discusses the [wizard dialog problem](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/csharpgeneral/thread/9af01889-b4bc-4aba-876e-f298ec31a109) and the various approaches to it, along with some more useful links to more implementations.

And DevExpress have a commercial [Wizard](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/C2C412FD-BD28-4E3B-9C20-4DC381AC5199) control if you have a budget for components and want to save some time and efforts.